# is it possible for two fields with the same characteristic to not be isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I know there is a long list of invariants, but is there a proof or theorem that explains two fields with the same characteristic are isomorphic?

Comment: Isomorphic in what sense?  Field isomorphism, set bijection, order isomorphism, etc?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$, $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$?

Comment: Isomorphic in the sense of rings. The two fields are rings with the same characteristic. Does this make them isomorphic?

Comment: What even made you think that it might not be possible? Just curious...

Comment: It's a homework question. We can't use invariants to prove two rings are isomorphic... But we can conclude that two rings that are fields with the same characteristic are isomorphic?  Seems odd to me. I'm wondering if anyone has some ideas as to why and how this is true.

Comment: Your question is strange enough that merely answering it is probably not what will really help you.  You say that this is a homework question: could you be more specific?  What is the exact question asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example to your question would be $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$. The first one is your favorite field of two elements. The second one is a field of 4 elements. They are not isomorphic (There is not even a bijection between them!) they both have characteristic 2.

Comment: Is this slide wrong written then http://crypto.biu.ac.il/winterschool2013/NigelSmart-BIU2013.pdf?

Comment: @curious which slide?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to define it. Slide 37

Comment: It is true that any two finite fields of the same cardinality are isomorphic. The characteristic is a good way to tell that two fields are NOT isomorphic, but not the other way around @curious.

Answer (score 14):

Every finite field of prime power order has characteristic $p$, but none of the fields $$\mathbb{F}_p, \mathbb{F}_{p^2}, \mathbb{F}_{p^3}, \dots$$

are isomorphic as fields; they don't even have the same cardinality.

---

Likewise, $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are infinite non-isomorphic fields of characteristic $0$. Even better, $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ are not isomorphic as fields, even thought they *do* have the same characteristic and cardinality.

Comment: +1, very nice. Just to really hammer the point home, STquestion, it may even be the case that you can have a finite field and an infinite field with the same nonzero characteristic. For example, $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$ have the same characteristic, where $\mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$ is the fraction field of $\mathbb{F}_{p}[t]$.

Comment: This is very helpful, but now I am curious.  Can you explain what a finite field of prime power is?  Can you give me an example?  Field (3^2) has char(3) and Field (3^3) has char(3) but different cardinalities...therefore, they are not isomorphic?  Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can always get non-isomorphic fields of a given characteristic by picking two of different cardinality. And you can always get fields as large as you want by formally adjoining as many independent variables as you care to, and taking the field of fractions of the resulting integral domain.

For finite fields, it is true that all fields of a given cardinality are isomorphic (the cardinality must be a prime power, and this prime is necessarily the characteristic).

For algebraically closed fields, the isomorphism class is uniquely specified by the characteristic and transcendence degree. In particular, all uncountable algebraically closed fields of a given characteristic and cardinality are isomorphic.

For infinite non-algebraically closed fields, however, you can't say much, because problems can be very explicit - for instance, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \not\cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ because one has an element whose square is $2$ but no element whose square is $3$, while the other has an element whose square is $3$ but no element whose square is $2$.